# WCF RESTful Service Configuration Getting 404

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

I am trying to make a simple WCF RESTful for the first time to be consumed via JSON. I have my interface below, but what would be the URL I would call to invoke my MemberLogon() method?

I thought it would be this:

```
http://localhost:49701/Exchange.svc/?membershipNumber=6519548&blah=abc
```

but I get a 404. I have a feeling it is to do with my service configuraiton in my Web.Config. Help!

My interface and class is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExchange
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract(Name = "MemberLogon")]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/?membershipNumber={membershipNumber}&blah={blah}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Member MemberLogon(string membershipNumber, string blah);
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class Member
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration is:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyNamespace.MyClass.ExchangeBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.MyClass.ExchangeBehavior" name="MyNamespace.MyClass.Exchange">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.MyClass.IExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code and interface look good.  Can you try this configuration?

```
<system.serviceModel>
            <behaviors>
              <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyNamespace.MyClass.ExchangeBehavior">
                  <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
              </endpointBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <services>
              <service name="MyNamespace.MyClass.Exchange">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.MyClass.ExchangeBehavior" contract="MyNamespace.MyClass.IExchange" />
              </service>
            </services>
       </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I just got it correctly invoked with your configuration using this URL: http://localhost:49701/Exchange.svc/?membershipNumber=6519548&blah=abc but how can I specify the method to call (e.g. invoke MemberLogon)?

Comment: Scratch that comment - you are a STAR :) I just had to modify the UriTemplate. THANK YOU SO MUCH.